# Play Video as the Background on iPhone on button click?

Tags: ios, video, background

I want to create an app which has a default image as the background of a view that has many buttons on it. When a user clicks on any of the buttons, a unique video plays. The buttons are gonna be almost transparent so, I want the video to play in the background of the same view itself  (replacing/playing above the image) and not open in a new Player(as it does using the media player). Has anyone tried it, or does anyone have any idea?

Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#import <MediaPlayer/MPMoviePlayerController.h>
MPMoviePlayerController* moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: [NSURL fileURLWithPath: moviePath]];
moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
[RootViewController.view insertSubview: moviePlayer.view aboveSubview: myView];
[moviePlayer play];
```

Comment: Hey, I am new to this stuff, and this question might sound stupid. What is the 'RootViewController', isn't it the 'viewController' that is set in the app delegate? Also, do u mean 'myView' to be 'self.view' ?

Comment: Yes, `RootViewController` is main controller of your app. I don't know hierarchy of your views, but you need to insert `moviePlayer.view` above background view. `[moviePlayer play];` should be called in your play-button callback.

Comment: Thank You, I used your approach except that i made the changes in the xib.     
    *For anyone else looking for how i did it:
I just added a new view to my xib file and moved the view below my buttons and restricted fullscreen access to the player(but I made the dimensions of the new view the same as the screen size, hence it plays in full screen, but below my buttons).